# unable to access HttpUtils.httpConnection class in eclipse editor

Tags: android

I am working on MMS application , I need to use 'httpConnection' method of 'HttpUtils' class, but unable to access this,  please suggest me where I did wrong..

do I need to add any extra JAR's for this...??
I am using Android 2.3V..

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

try this one out:
   http://code.google.com/p/meneameandroid/source/browse/trunk/src/com/dcg/util/HttpManager.java

I'm using that class in quite some apps. The class perfroms post/get requests.

Comment: Hi I am unable to use HttpManager.java also, plz tell me which JAR file I need to add to to use this..

Comment: Just the plain Android SDK. Once I get access to my system I'll try to make a test with 2.3.